# Stop website because of startup errors

Tags: c#, iis

If my web service runs into some initialization error during startup, such as not being able to connect to its database, is it possible for me to stop the website? This will make it easier for administrators to see that something has gone wrong without checking the log files and would analogous to terminating an application early if the command line parameters are wrong. One more caveat, I can't use `Microsoft.Web.Administration`.

Answer (score 0):

You could raise a specific type of Exception for those fatal errors and handle it on Application_Error.

When those catastrophic events happen and are handled there you could just generate an `App_Offline.htm` that'll bring the website down without phisically stopping it on IIS.

This will make your website return `503 Service Unavailable` which is probably the most semantically correct way of a web service communicating it's down because of a catastrophic event.